# Using JavaScript in Android Studio

Tags: javascript, android

I would like to ask a one question; I'm starting with learning of JS for web-development purposes and I heard that it can be used in Android Studio as well (with html, css). So What is the difference in Android Studio between using JS and Java? Is it harder to write?

Comment: You mean to build Android Application, right? Android Studio is just an development environment where you use Native (Java or Kotlin) languages to build android application.

Comment: You can't use JavaScript in Android Studio but you can make JavaScript based Android Applications. Not in Android Studio, but though some other development environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there are some Android Studio plugins you could install to have your JS code highlighted, but I'm not sure that's a good idea to use it to learn web development. Android Studio has been created for developing Android applications and it focuses on optimizing the process of development using Java or Kotlin (and I believe from recently also Dart). Support of any other programming language is just an additional feature.

If you are used to AS UI and functionalities I would recommend checking out [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/). It's very similar to IntelliJ, the IDE that AS is based on. Unfortunately it's paid, but there is a 30-day trial and if you happen to be a student, you can get a full version for free (of course for educational purposes only)

However if you're looking for a fully free tool, I heard that [VisualStudio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is a great tool as well.