# Javascript in Android Studio

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, android-studio, extension-methods

How can I show javascript extension in android studio while writing an API in android studio using nodejs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using JavaScript in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56944129/using-javascript-in-android-studio)

Comment: Not really. I think there should be a plugin for using javascript in android studio.